# What are some free dynamic workout routine generator apps?

Tags: workout-routines, routine

I am looking for a free app which I can use to generate a workout routine according to my fitness level (12 pullups, 40 push ups..), my resources (at home with dumbells & pullup bar), my goals (have nice looking arms & shoulders), amount of time I can spend weekly(200mins, 5 days a week)and so on.

I want the app to be able to change my future programs according to the amount of sets & amount of reps I do on the earlier workouts.

What are some of the app that can do such thing?

Comment: **200 mins** *(3 hrs 20 mins)* each day or for a week?

Comment: Forty minutes each day for five days?

Comment: Since @David Liepmann is too nice to plug his own app, I will. His app is called "maketired" and does almost exactly what you're looking for. It's geared toward conditioning routines for after strength training.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD & rrirower those are just examples, dont get stuck to the details, the main idea is that when someone enters their data the program should be able to generate a routine.

Comment: @half-pass Thanks for the plug! I'm flattered. :)

Comment: If you have 3 hrs a day, the routines you'll need will certainly be different from the ones needed if it's just 40 mins a day; however, it seems the timeline is irrelevant.

Comment: @David Liepmann, of course! It's a very nice app!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because (From the FAQ) every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Answer (score 2):

You may want an app, but to me it sounds like what you're looking for is a coach. Your requirements read like the list of services Fitocracy's online coaches offer ([example](https://www.fitocracy.com/team-fitness/308/private-coaching-with-ben-with-ben-hessel/?1&utm_source=fitocracy&utm_medium=trainer_profile&utm_campaign=bio&utm_content=nio1&ref=trainer_profile) -- I am not affiliated with the site or the coaches, I use the free app).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this app called [Jefit](http://jefit.com), which is fairly popular, you might have already heard of it.

I've created my own routine (based on the equipment available to me) and can record reps and weight for each exercise. They have quite an exhaustive list of exercises for you to choose from broken down by which body part they push.

Using this, I can see how much I was able to do in my previous session of, say biceps, and how much I need to do this time to beat myself. This way, I am always competing against myself in the gym, and can see growth by just the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Urban, i also use Jefit.

While i did my own routine (based on the book Bigger, leaner, stronger by Michael Matthews), the app also features community workouts made by other people, these workouts can be filtered by ranking meaning you can chose to follow popular workouts with great reviews.

The large workout database allows you to vary your routine if that's what you are looking for (although i would recommend keeping the same routine for some weeks since it allows you to directly compare your gains by keeping track of the weight improvement).